# android frame-by-frame animation and translation

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to code an animation that consists of a bird flying. So I've a sequence of PNGs that i can compose using an animation list, and then start with an AnimationDrawable. I'd like to also translate the bird. This can be done with a tween animationtranslate.

However, the two methods can't be composed.. As I understand, tween animations can be only composed with an animation set that consists of translations, rotations, alphas, and scale, but not frame-by-frame!

Ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

not sure this is the answer you are looking for.
I few time ago I tried to use animation class and I figure out to be very complex or even limited. So I guess if you want to make simple animations just do it Raw by changing the Rectangle attributes by period of time. This can be easily done onDraw()
You have some very good video tutorials in youtube.
check it out
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1e17InAx_w

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. Before digging on that I'd like to know whether it can be done using Android's builtin animation tools :)